# Animate my output trajectory to be a moving line

Tags: python, jquery-animate

I am very much a novice but using python for my master's thesis.

I have a .csv of x and y coordinates grouped by 'frame'.  I would like to animate it, so that it is a growing line as it moves frame by frame but I can't figure out how.

The data points are mouse movements that follow an individual dolphin through a drone video.  So each x,y represents the dolphin's placement in the video frame.

This is what I have so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis_Data/2016-07-17-1542_2A.csv', 
                 usecols=['x', 'y','frame'])
df.head(10)
```

This is what my data looks like.  I have a few thousand points.

```
  frame   x     y
0   61  1057    487
1   61  1057    487
2   61  1057    487
3   61  1057    487
4   61  1057    487
5   61  1057    487
6   61  1057    487
7   61  1057    487
8   61  1057    487
9   61  1057    487
```

```
gr = df.groupby('frame')
```

```
mean_pos = gr.mean()
ax= df.plot("x", "y", color="r")
ax.set_title('mean trajectory')
```

[output trajectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJax5.png)

I want to animate it so that it moves by frame like a moving line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd

# a sample dataframe  with coordinates of random movement
xy = np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 2)).cumsum(axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(xy, columns=["x", "y"])

# plot setup
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
ax.set_xlim(df["x"].min() - 2, df["x"].max() + 2)
ax.set_ylim(df["y"].min() - 2, df["y"].max() + 2)
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')

def update(i):
    """
    updates the plot for each animation frame
    """
    ln.set_data(df.iloc[0:i, 0], df.iloc[0:i, 1])
    return ln,

# animate the plot
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, 
                    update, 
                    frames=len(df), 
                    interval=100, # delay of each frame in miliseconds
                    blit=True)
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Note: If you want to run this in Jupyter Notebook execute the `%matplotlib notebook` magic first.

Comment: Thanks.  I think i'm getting closer.  I am getting this error.  Even when i try to recreate your suggestion:
RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.

Comment: @JillianBliss I am sorry, while making edits I omitted one line. It should work fine now.